# issue in Spring @pathvariable

Tags: spring-mvc

I have written a controller

```
package org.arpan.spring.mvc;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;


@Controller
public class HelloController {





    @RequestMapping(value="/hello")
    public String getMessage(ModelMap model)
    {
        model.addAttribute("message", "Hello this is my first spring project!");
        return "Hello";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/hey/{username}")
    public String getMessage(ModelMap model,@PathVariable String username)
    {
        System.out.println(username);
        model.addAttribute("message", "Hey this is my first spring project!");
        return "Hello1";
    }


    @RequestMapping(value="/hi/{id}")
    public String getMessage1( ModelMap model,@PathVariable("username2") String id)
    {
        model.addAttribute("message", "Hi this is my first spring project!");
        return "Hello";
    }


}
```

when i run this /hello works fine but the second /hey/{username} and third /hi/{username} does not works giving error as below

URL : http://localhost:8080/FirstSpringMVCProject/hey/abc

HTTP Status 404 - /FirstSpringMVCProject/hey/WEB-INF/jsp/Hello1.jsp

Comment: Its because the way you have configured your view handler, it is searching for Hello1.jsp or Hello1.html. And I guess you do not have Hello1.xxx.

Comment: no i have Hello1.jsp file too in WEB-INF/jsp/ and the view resolver looks like this     
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
<property name="prefix" value="WEB-INF/jsp/" />
<property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

</beans>

Answer (score 1):

Just one correction in view resolver will solve the problem

```
 <bean id="viewResolver" class ="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it solved my problem but the question is why it was working for /hello but not for /hey/{username}

Comment: @ArpanPaliwal If it solved your problem. can you please accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells that it is trying to look for Hello1.jsp.
Can you verify if your jsp file is named hello1.jsp or Hello1.jsp. The case should be same.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion but it is the same.